# Query regarding Global Variable Instantiation in ASP.NET MVC on more than one terminals

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm quite new to ASP.NET MVC  (or .NET in general), so it might sound like a very basic (and probably a stupid) question. But please hear me out.

I have a separate class file where I store all the global variables that are required to be set and get at various stages of a workflow.

Something like this (a partial list):

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    private static int loginKey;
    public static string LoggedUser;
    public static string UserRole;
    public static int GblRegID;
    public static string NewMemID;
}
```

**My question is**: If the application is running on two different machines simultaneously, will these variables be instantiated at those two terminals independently? Or is it going to be a situation where the value set by the first terminal will be accessible from the second terminal?

Reason for my question: in one of the applications, I had set the logged-in user name to a global variable and was using it to save as a "Modified By" or "Added By" name for all the records from that terminal. However, we found during testing; that the name from the first terminal was getting captured and saved for the records on the second terminal. I resolved that situation by using cookies.

But with this new requirement, I would like to know more about the global variable instantiation. Also, while we are at it, is using cookies an acceptable solution from a security/best practice point of view?

This is a theoretical and logic-based question.

**Desired result**: I would like to define the global variables that will work independently on each terminal running the same application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are only shared within the same process, never across multiple processes, and neither are they automatically persisted.

In general you should avoid global variables as they will make the code difficult to maintain and reason about. In my experience, you never need them; there's always a better design option.

Comment: Note that this is basically wrong for question tagged with ASP.Net (where all callers will see the same instance in basic cases as all requests would be served by the same process)... It is unlikely that @WarSam actaully asked about ASP.Net so :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - my question was related to ASP.Net MVC, hence the tag. As the first sentence of my question indicates. If I'm understanding you correctly, do you beg to differ with Mark Seemann's response? If yes, Why?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Which parts of my answer are "basically wrong" just because of the tag?

Comment: MarkSeemann normally when one runs a web site (i.e. ASP.Net MVC) the site's code runs on one server (ignoring professional cases of multiple servers behind load balancers/CDNs) and accessed from multiple user devices using browser. In this case static variables indeed would be shared across all "users" (which are just requests to the same running process on the server). While your answer is technically correct (the reason for upvote) it does not answer the question OP should have asked based on ASP.Net tag... I have no idea what @WarSam mean "first terminal" (sounds like console app to me)...

Comment: ... so it  is quite hard to know what project they actually setup. (It is quite common to see ASP.Net used as synonym for "C# console app" on SO... without a real [mre] words OP used could mean anything)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Apologies for the terminologies.. but you were on target. I meant to say an application running on a server and it is accessed by two devices at the same time. For clarity, the ASP.Net MVC project I was referring to was developed using C# and it's a Web Application in VS 2019. Based on your explanation, all the static variables will be shared across all users. Thank you. Can you also please tell us if using Cookies is an acceptable solution? or can you suggest one?

Also can you please put your comment as an answer to help others and future users looking for it